# Python - exporting results to .csv file

Tags: python, csv, export

I need a python script to run the model number of times and save the result (MAEValue) for all runs in CSV file.

```py
model = SVR(kernel = 'rbf',gamma=0.032 ,C=16187.696941074802) # it also can be : linear, poly, linear, linear, precomputed
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('Grey Wolf Train Score is : ' , model.score(X_train, y_train))
print('Grey Wolf Test Score is : ' , model.score(X_test, y_test))
y_preda = model.predict(X_test)
#Calculating Mean Absolute Error
MAEValue1 = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_preda, multioutput='uniform_average') # it can be raw_values
print(MAEValue1)
```

Comment: `with open('path_to_filename_.csv','a') as fp:  fp.write(data) fp.write('\n') ` will do

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty dataframe before the runs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['result'])
```

And then every time you get `MAEValue1` enter it to the `df` with:

```
df.loc['unique_name_of_run'] = MAEValue1
```

Finally (after all the runs) save it with:

```
df.to_csv('my_file.csv')
```

Comment: thank u  ,  but if I want to run more than one model and get results for all in the same CSV file!